# Possible to Create Table (SQL Query) Field with Format property set?

Tags: ms-access

Maybe a dumb question, but I'm wondering if I create a table using SQL Query, is there a way to set its Format or Input Mask? I tried searching for the answer before asking.

```
CREATE TABLE StudentsTable
(    [SID] AUTOINCREMENT,
     [Student Name] TEXT(255) NOT NULL,
     [Student Number] TEXT(255) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_studentsTable PRIMARY KEY ([SID])
);
```

```
INSERT INTO StudentsTable
VALUES (1, 'John Doe', '(111) 222-3333');
```

| SID | Student Name | Student Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | (111) 222-3333 |

Contrived example, but you get the gist.

I've already created the table and forms using the design/layout views, now my class is creating the table and populating it using SQL queries.

I'm wondering if I can set the Format property of a field I create so that when I populate the table with another series of queries that I can just supply raw numbers like 1112223333 and change the field to Integer as opposed to the current setup.

I'm sure VBA can do this, I'd just much prefer to do it with a query, ideally within the CREATE TABLE query.

Comment: Use VBA and DAO for this.

Comment: I seldom set these properties in table. I just format controls on form and report. An integer field for digital identifiers won't work if they have leading zeros. I suppose phone numbers don't but I would leave it as text anyway.

Comment: Be wary of using formatted integers for fields that have no numeric meaning (e.g. addition/division is meaningless). It tends to gain you a tiny bit of reduced storage and increased performance, but leads to trouble when exporting, copying using queries that don't preserve formatting, working with the data in external systems, etc.

Comment: @June7 _I suppose phone numbers don't_: that's a very dangerous assumption, all international phone numbers either start with two zeroes or a +. Storing phone numbers as an integer/double is something you should never do, and generally you should allocate a lot more space than you initially expect for a phone number (14-digit phone numbers are certainly not impossible, for example).